# XML Schema minOccurs / maxOccurs default values

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm wondering how the XML Schema specification handles these cases:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="asdf"/>
```

No maxOccurs given -> Is this the cardinality [1..1]?

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="2" name="asdf"/>
```

I suppose this is simply invalid?

```
<xsd:element maxOccurs="2" name="asdf"/>
```

Is this the cardinality [0..2] or [1..2]?

Is there an "official" definition on how the XML Schema spec handles these cases?

Answer (score 369, accepted):

The default values for `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` are 1. Thus:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="asdf"/>
```

cardinality is [1-1] Note: if you specify *only* minOccurs attribute, it can't be greater than 1, because the default value for maxOccurs is 1.

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="2" name="asdf"/>
```

invalid

```
<xsd:element maxOccurs="2" name="asdf"/>
```

cardinality is [1-2] Note: if you specify *only* maxOccurs attribute, it can't be smaller than 1, because the default value for minOccurs is 1.

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0"/>
```

is a valid combination which makes the element prohibited.

For more info see http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints

Comment: <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0"/> is not working in my case.

Comment: In that case, don't define that element in the xsd

Answer (score 102):

<sub>*New, expanded answer to an old, commonly asked question...*</sub>

### Default Values

- Occurrence constraints `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` **default to `1`**.

---

### Common Cases Explained

```
<xsd:element name="A"/>
```

means `A` is ***required*** and must appear ***exactly once***.

---

```
<xsd:element name="A" minOccurs="0"/>
```

means `A` is ***optional*** and may appear ***at most once***.

---

```
 <xsd:element name="A" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

means `A` is ***required*** and may repeat an ***unlimited number of times***.

---

```
 <xsd:element name="A" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

means `A` is ***optional*** and may repeat an ***unlimited number of times***.

---

### See Also

- [W3C XML Schema Part 0: Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints)

  > In general, an element is required to appear when the value of
  >   minOccurs is 1 or more. The maximum number of times an element may
  >   appear is determined by the value of a maxOccurs attribute in its
  >   declaration. This value may be a positive integer such as 41, or the
  >   term unbounded to indicate there is no maximum number of occurrences.
  >   The default value for both the minOccurs and the maxOccurs attributes
  >   is 1. Thus, when an element such as comment is declared without a
  >   maxOccurs attribute, the element may not occur more than once. Be sure
  >   that if you specify a value for only the minOccurs attribute, it is
  >   less than or equal to the default value of maxOccurs, i.e. it is 0 or 1.
  >   Similarly, if you specify a value for only the maxOccurs attribute, it must be greater than or equal to the default value of minOccurs,
  >   i.e. 1 or more. If both attributes are omitted, the element must
  >   appear exactly once.
- [W3C XML Schema Part 1: Structures Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#element-element)

  ```
  <element
    maxOccurs = (nonNegativeInteger | unbounded)  : 1
    minOccurs = nonNegativeInteger : 1
    >

  </element>
  ```

Comment: Whilst this is defo in the spec linked I found that my validating parser failed for a maxOccurs of say 1M. Seems in my case I had to set it to unbounded. See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58024961/1279002

Comment: @theINtoy: Your comment and the linked answer it references are about idiosyncratic limitations of particular implementations.  A better Q/A citation for implementation limitations is [What is the maximum integer for maxOccurs in a XSD XML Schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20354344/290085)

Comment: I get the reason for your response. To clarify my comment further, I probably should have stated that using javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory to parse a XSD contained in a string, having a value of maxOccurs within the nonNegativeInteger bounds did not work for larger values. Setting a value to unbounded allowed the schema to parse.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

As written in xsd:

```
<xs:attribute name="minOccurs" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" use="optional" default="1"/>
<xs:attribute name="maxOccurs" type="xs:allNNI" use="optional" default="1"/>
```

If you provide an attribute with number, then the number is boundary. **Otherwise attribute should appear exactly once**.