# Does Schema Define Number of Elements?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have recently started with XML and had a question regarding XML schemas. As I understand schemas define a sort of contract that all XML files that implement the schema, will follow.

Take, for example, this schema: http://estar8.energystar.gov/ESES/ABS20/Schemas/ManageMetersResponse.xsd

The root contains three children: txnsID, espUserID and customer. I've read up on schemas and I think I am OK, but I am looking after someone's code and the code calls

```
root.getAllChildrenByNameOf("customer")
```

instead of

```
root.getChildByNameOf("customer")
```

which makes me think that there might be multiple customer elements, while I think the schema defines that only one may exist per document. Any clarifications? Thanks for your time.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821477/xml-schema-minoccurs-maxoccurs-default-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema you linked to allows any number of "customer" elements. The relevant portion is this attribute:

```
maxOccurs="unbounded"
```

This means the element can repeat any number of times.

Comment: It seems I did not read up on default indicators. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

The schema has a maxOccurs of unbounded for the customer node. This means it can occur any number of times