# How to make an element in XML schema optional?

Tags: xml, xsd

So I got this XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="request">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="amenity">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element> </xs:schema>
```

How do I make the description element optional? So both XML with the description element and without will validate against the XSD.

Comment: See also [***XML Schema minOccurs / maxOccurs default values***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4821477/290085)

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Try this

```
<xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
```

if you want 0 or 1 "description" elements, Or

```
<xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
```

if you want 0 to infinity number of "description" elements.

Comment: You beat me to the answer, but here's a useful link:  http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints

Comment: `maxOccurs` defaults to `1`, so your top example doesn't need to specify it.

Comment: Indeed, tested it, and you only need to specify minOccurs="0" to make it optional if you want to allow one element max.

Comment: maxOccurs defaulting to 1 - very useful info, thank you.

Comment: Thank you! This [link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_indicators.asp) contains others informations

Answer (score 24):

Set the `minOccurs` attribute to `0` in the schema like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="request">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="amenity">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element> </xs:schema>
```