# No minOccurs, maxOccurs

Tags: java, wsdl

When we don't declare any minOccurs and maxOccurs in WSDL declaration is that taking default values? or is that ignore minOccurs and maxOccurs values?

Comment: See [XML Schema minOccurs / maxOccurs default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821477/xml-schema-minoccurs-maxoccurs-default-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes thats true. The default values for minOccurs and maxOccurs are 1. Also not that when you provide only minOccurance attribute, then it can not be greater than 1, as the default value for maxOccurance is 1 and vice versa.

Also check the [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints).

Comment: Thanks Rahul. That means it takes default values.. eventhough we don't mention

Comment: @AshaPerera:- Indeed!

Comment: Small clarification :-) If I have element like <element name="CONN_TYPE"> I don't define any minOccurance and maxOccurance value still it takes default value. I don't want a mandotory value. It can be optional. In this case because of default value it bocomes a mandatory value???

Comment: @AshaPerera:- To keep it simple, its just that if you dont define it then it would take the default value.