# XML Schema Validation for unknown elements

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I am trying to validate the XML with the schema in C#. I will be having an unknown elements under the row element. I am using `xs:any`, I am getting the below error

> The element 'row' has invalid child element 'Name'.

Schema -

```
<xs:element name="table">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="row">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any processContents="lax"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

XML -

```
<table>
  <row>
    <ProductID>994</ProductID>
    <Name>LL Bottom Bracket</Name>
    <ProductModel>LL Bottom Bracket</ProductModel>
    <CultureID>en    </CultureID>
    <Description>Chromoly steel.</Description>
  </row> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not specified a `maxOccurs` on the `xs:any`, **[and `maxOccurs` defaults to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33686479/290085)**, which means that the second element, `Name`, is not allowed, thus the error message,

> The element 'row' has invalid child element 'Name'.

Correct by adding `maxOccurs="unbounded"` to `xs:any`:

```
        <xs:any processContents="lax" macOccurs="unbounded"/>
```