# XSD choice element with maxOccurs="unbounded" containing elements with maxOccurs="1"

Tags: xml, xsd, exchangewebservices

In this example (from Exchange Web Services XSD)

```
 <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfAttendeeConflictData">
     <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
         <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="UnknownAttendeeConflictData" nillable="true" type="t:UnknownAttendeeConflictData" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="IndividualAttendeeConflictData" nillable="true" type="t:IndividualAttendeeConflictData" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TooBigGroupAttendeeConflictData" nillable="true" type="t:TooBigGroupAttendeeConflictData" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="GroupAttendeeConflictData" nillable="true" type="t:GroupAttendeeConflictData" />
     </xs:choice>
 </xs:complexType>
```

Does it mean a valid XML can have `UnknownAttendeeConflictData`, `IndividualAttendeeConflictData`, `TooBigGroupAttendeeConflictData` and `GroupAttendeeConflictData` in any order but only one instance of each?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, alone `maxOccurences="1"` on the children of `xs:choice` will ***not*** prohibit the children of `xsd:choice` from appearing more than once.

`maxOccurs="unbounded"` on `xsd:choice` means that there can be an unbounded number of choices.  For each such choice, the XML document will be able to have one occurrence due to the `maxOccurences="1"`, but next time around this can repeat due to `xsd:choice/@maxOccurences="unbounded"`.  So those elements listed as children of an `xsd:choice/@maxOccurences="unbounded"` will be able to appear multiple times in any order.

If as an XSD author you want such elements to appear once in any order, consider using `xsd:all`.   Also note that [occurrence constraints `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` default to 1 anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4821477/290085), so listing them explicitly isn't really required.