# cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'tns:patient' is not complete

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation, xmlschemaset

In the below xsd I am trying to create a list of 10 patients using the same schema. When I validate the xml file I get an error saying cvc complex type 2.4.b.Is there any other way I can use to create a list of 10 patients with the same schema definition.

XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  targetNamespace="http://www.hennaloungani.com/Patient"
xmlns:tns="http://www.hennaloungani.com/Patient"  elementFormDefault="qualified">

 <element name="patient" type="tns:Patient" />
<complexType name="Patient">
    <sequence>
        <element name="patient" type="tns:Patient" maxOccurs="10" />
        <element name="name" type="tns:Sting15Char"></element>
        <element name="age" type="int"></element>
        <element name="dob" type="date"></element>
        <element name="email" type="string" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
        <element name="gender" type="tns:Gender"></element>
        <element name="phone" type="string"></element>
        <element name="payment" type="tns:PaymentType"></element>
    </sequence>

    <attribute name="id" type="tns:ID"></attribute>
    </complexType>


    <complexType name="PaymentType">
        <choice>
            <element name="Cash" type="int"></element>
            <element name="Insurance" type="tns:Insurance"></element>
        </choice>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="Insurance">
        <all>
            <element name="provider" type="string"></element>
            <element name="limit" type="int"></element>

        </all>

    </complexType>
    <simpleType name="ID">
        <restriction base="int">
            <pattern value="[0-100]"></pattern>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>

    <simpleType name="Sting15Char">
        <restriction base="string">
            <maxLength value="15"></maxLength>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="Gender">
        <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="M"></enumeration>
            <enumeration value="F"></enumeration>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
```

I am getting this error at line 2 : cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'tns:patient' is not complete. One of '{"http://
 www.hennaloungani.com/Patient":patient}' is expected

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:patient id="1" xmlns:tns="http://www.hennaloungani.com/Patient"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hennaloungani.com/Patient Patient.xsd ">
<tns:patient id="1" />
<tns:name>tns:name</tns:name>
<tns:age>0</tns:age>
<tns:dob>2001-01-01</tns:dob>
<tns:email>tns:email</tns:email>
<tns:gender>M</tns:gender>
<tns:phone>tns:phone</tns:phone>
<tns:payment>
    <tns:Cash>0</tns:Cash>
</tns:payment>
```

Comment: What does it actually *mean* for a patient to contain another patient?

Comment: I am actually trying to use the same scehma definition of the patient to create a record for 9 other patients. I am learning how to do it. Any other way of doing it will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but I wouldn't dream of trying to design an XML document representing patient information without first getting stakeholders together for an information modelling and requirements gathering workshop; it's an exercise that's completely outside the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: Incidentally your pattern for the ID type allows only the values 000 and 100. If you want any integer from 0 to 100 (still a rather odd choice for an ID...) then use minInclusive and maxInclusive facets.

Comment: @MichaelKay I am trying to use a  real time scenario to learn the implementation of XML. Its just a practice exercise. Hence, the id range is from 000-100.Thank you for the suggestion though. I'll look up information related to minInclusive and maxInclusive facets and how to implement them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `patient` child of the `patient` root element of the XML has no children of its own, yet the XSD says that `patient` elements must have a sequence of  various child elements (`patient`, `name`, `age`, etc).

If you want to have any hope of instantiating a valid XML document for your XSD, you'll at least have to make the `patient` child element be optional: `minOccurs="0"`.  Otherwise, your XSD will be specifying an infinite recursion of `patient` descendants.  Note that [by default, `minOccurs="1"`, which means that the element is required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33686479/290085).

If you want to allow your XML as-is (with an empty `patient` child element) to validate, similarly add `minOccurs="0"` to each of the declarations for `name`, `age`, `dob`, etc.