# Invalid content was found starting with element.'catalog_item'

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am getting an error saying *Error - Line 16, 38: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 38; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'catalog_item'. No child element is expected at this point.* Line 16. I am supposed to write an xsd to validate a given xml file.

This is the xml file given to me.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
         <price>39.95</price>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
      <catalog_item gender="Women's">
         <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
         <price>42.50</price>
         <size description="Small">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Extra Large">
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

And this is my xsd file for the above xml file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="catalog">
   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="product">
      <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="catalog_item">
         <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="item_number">
            <xs:simpleType>
             <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"/>
             </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
           </xs:element>
           <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="size" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="color_swatch" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                  <xs:attribute name="image" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
   <xs:attribute name="gender" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
 </xs:sequence>
 <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:attribute name="product_image" type="xs:string"/>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[The `maxOccurs` occurrence constraint defaults to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33686479/290085)**, so your XSD only allows for one `catalog_item`, yet your XML has two.

To allow multiple `catalog_item` elements, add `maxOccurs="unbounded"`...

Change

```
    <xs:element name="catalog_item">
```

to

```
    <xs:element name="catalog_item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```