# Migrating to CXF 3.2.7 -> How to solve the password related security error during SOAP RQ processing?

Tags: java, soap, cxf, ws-security, wss4j

**Context** : I am trying to migrate a webservice from CXF 2.2.2 to CXF 3.2.7

**Problem** : 
Post migration whenever i try to fire the below HTTP-POST SOAP based request against my webservice through a software like SOAP UI :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="">
        <wsse:Username>sampleUser</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>12345</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:PartnerID>samplePartner</wsse:PartnerID>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
    <wsa:To>http://localhost:8080/sampleWs</wsa:To>
    <wsa:Action>http://localhost:8080/sampleWs/sampleAction</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:From>
      <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
</wsa:From>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

I receive the following security exception from CXF security module :

```
18:11:29,250 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (http-127.0.0.1:8080-1) Interceptor for {http://ws.sampleWs.varun/}SampleWebService has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: A security error was encountered when verifying the message
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JUtils.createSoapFault(WSS4JUtils.java:234) [cxf-rt-ws-security-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:341) [cxf-rt-ws-security-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:176) [cxf-rt-ws-security-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:87) [cxf-rt-ws-security-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        .
        .
        .
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: BSP:R4201: Any PASSWORD MUST specify a Type attribute
        at org.apache.wss4j.common.bsp.BSPEnforcer.handleBSPRule(BSPEnforcer.java:57) [wss4j-ws-security-common-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.token.UsernameToken.checkBSPCompliance(UsernameToken.java:834) [wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.token.UsernameToken.<init>(UsernameToken.java:143) [wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.UsernameTokenProcessor.handleUsernameToken(UsernameTokenProcessor.java:137) [wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.UsernameTokenProcessor.handleToken(UsernameTokenProcessor.java:62) [wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.engine.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:340) [wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:285) [cxf-rt-ws-security-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        ... 28 more
```

The root cause appears to be a missing attribute in `wsse:password` tag.

I checked the security WS specs : 
http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd

There i could not find a mandatory type attribute for `wsse:password`as expected by latest CXF.

***Note*** :  The same request is processed fine by CXF version 2.2.2

**Question** : 
Is there a way for preventing CXF from dropping the above request and allow it go through.
I looked around a lot but couldnt find any answers ? Any suggestions ?
OR modfifying the SOAP request is the only solution ?

Comment: Not providing a solution to your problem, but the XSD you mention DOES mandate a type attribute (wsse:Password is of type PasswordString, which extends AttributedString, which has a mandatory type). Further more, the XSD is just the translation of basic requirement profile http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicsecurityprofile-1.1.html rule R4201

Comment: Thankyou for the spot ! Pardon me for my stupidity, but you are saying that because `minOccurs="0"` is absent in `AttributedString` ? Also if thats the case i would still keep this question open, in case somebody has a solution.

Comment: Generally speaking, in the XSD spec, when the cardinality is not specified, the default is mandatory and only one occurence (minOccurs = maxOccurs =1). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821477/xml-schema-minoccurs-maxoccurs-default-values . But it does not even matter, because the spec (not the XSD) indicates that the attribute is mandatory, so even if the XSD was otherwise, WSS4J would check it anyway.

Comment: thanks for the info, could you by any chance provide me with the specs link ? OR keywords for a quick google search ?

Comment: You have the link in my first comment :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above request is being dropped because as stated earlier by @GPI, CXF tries to enforce R4201 of the Basic security specs (http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicsecurityprofile-1.1.html).

To prevent CXF from enforcing this we can use configuration constants provided by `ws-security` and `wss4j` that would instruct CXF to stop the enforcement.

**Solution #1 (Using WSS4J interceptor)**

In your spring config file, you can set `isBspCompliant` to `false` :

```
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                    <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                    <entry key="passwordCallbackRef">
                        <ref bean="passwordCallback" />
                    </entry>
                    <entry key="isBSPCompliant" value="false"/>
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
```

**Solution #2 (Using JAX-WS)**

In your spring config file, you can set `ws-security.is-bsp-compliant` to `false` :

```
    <jaxws:endpoint id="sample" implementor="sample.ws.SampleWebService" address="/SampleWebService">
    <jaxws:properties> 
    <entry key="ws-security.is-bsp-compliant" value="false"/> 
    </jaxws:properties> 
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

For additional configuration options, you can refer these pages :

http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/config.html

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and found out that there was an issue in the soap request.

I was able to resolve it by adding :

- the following attribute in the soap:Envelope `xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"`
- the following attribute in wsse:Password   `Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"`

The header of my request looked like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tic="http://ticket.degroupage.atos.ma/"  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>XXXX</wsse:Username>
         <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXX</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
     </wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
...
```