# XML enum value accepting null values

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

XML enum element (with max occurs > 1) is accepting

> ```
> "Status": [
>      null
>  ]
> ```

which I do not want. I only want to accept valid strings defined in the enum.

Have tried setting the restriction of the enum to minimum length of 1 which did not seem to solve the issue

```xml
<simpleType name="statusType">
        <restriction base="string" >

          <enumeration value="UNDER_VERIFICATION"></enumeration>
          <enumeration value="STOPPED"></enumeration>
        </restriction>
</simpletype>
```

usage:

```
 <element name="status" type="common:statusType"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">

</element>
```

Comment: I just re-read your question and see that your problem remained after setting `minOccurs="1"`.   See my answer confirming what your XSD and such a variation means at the XML level.  If your problem persists at the code level, state the language and post the problematic code for more specific help.  See [mcve].  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `status` element as defined will only be valid with either of the following values:

```
<status>UNDER_VERIFICATION</status>
<status>STOPPED</status>
```

While it will not be valid with no content,

```
<status></status>
```

the `status` element itself is currently not required because of `minOccurs="0"`.  Change that to `minOccurs="1"` to make the status element itself be required:

```
<element name="status" type="common:statusType"
         maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"/>
```

You may also omit `minOccurs` as its default value is `1`.  See [XML Schema minOccurs / maxOccurs default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4821477/290085) for further details.