# XSD for optional list of at least one element?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I want to make sure, that `<specials/>` can be optional, but when it occurs, I want to make sure, that it has at least one `<special>`.

Imagine the following XML:

```xml
<software>
  <programm id="123">
    <name>Editor</name>
    <specials>
      <special>Something really special here</special>
      <special>Something special as well</special>
    </specials>
  </programm>
  <programm id="456">
    <name>Another Editor</name>
  </programm>
</software>
```

My tried XSD for this is. This won't throw a validation error, if there is just `<specials></specials>` but no children inside.

```xml
<xs:element name="software">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="programm" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
                        <xs:element name="specials" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence minOccurs="1">
                                    <xs:element name="special" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="id" type="programmID"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
       </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: When I remove the `special` elements and validate with an empty `special` element, it does report a validation error: `The content of element 'specials' is not complete. One of '{special}' is expected`

Answer (score 1):

An XSD constraint for an optional `list` element of at least one `member` element can be expressed simply with `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs`:

```
          <xs:element name="list" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="member" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
```

> This won't throw a validation error, if there is just `<specials></specials>` but no children inside.

On the contrary, your XSD as written will fail to validate XML with an empty `specials` element as desired because it specifies that `specials` is optional but when present, its `special` child element must occur once.  In addition to this analytical observation, I have confirmed this behavior empirically via actual validation.

**Side notes:**

- `minOccurs="1"` is the default, so you can remove those throughout your XSD.
- `maxOccurs="1"` is the default, so you probably want `maxOccurs="unbounded"` on `special` to allow its repetition within `specials`.
- You do not need occurrence constraints on `xs:sequence` here.  Besides `minOccurs="1"` already being the default, there's only a single child in the sequence anyway, so it's unnecessary (and arguably distracting) to specify a group of one's occurrence constraints.

Here is a complete XSD that incorporates the above notes and validates your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="software">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="programm" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="specials" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="special" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### See also

- [XML Schema minOccurs / maxOccurs default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4821477/290085)